# Alternative to barplots with many bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to plot huge barplots where I want to check the distribution of one of my cases compared to the other :

```
require(distr)

N <- Norm(mean = 0.04559298, sd = 0.015826)
P <- Pois(lambda = 1.2)
Z <- 2*N + 3 + P
Zs <- r(Z)(1906)

myFun <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}

df <- data.frame(value = Zs, id = myFun(n = 1906))
df$type <- "type b"
df$type[sample(x = nrow(df), size = 200)] <- "type a"
df$case <- "1"

df2 <- data.frame(value = Zs, id = myFun(n = 1906))
df2$type <- "type b"
df2$type[sample(x = nrow(df2), size = 200)] <- "type a"
df2$case <- "2"

dfall <- rbind(df, df2)

ggplot(data = dfall, mapping = aes(x = reorder(id, -value),y=value, fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~case)
```

which gives me something like this :

[image]

However the spaces between each bars tend to be too visible probably because of some graphical rendering issues. The problem increases with facet_wrap. Honestly not sure if the problem is "real" but it is a bit confusing.

Do you know a better way to do this ?

Comment: I can't replicate the issue on my machine using the `ragg` plotting device - I get the bars all touching. If I run the code using the standard Windows device I get the same plot as you. Perhaps try switching to `ragg`?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this actually does the trick and solves the rmarkdown display. Plus it can be called as the device of ggsave which is great. I guess I'll export in pdf with classic device and see what I can do for more publishable versions.

Comment: It can also be used as the default display in RStudio. If you go into global settings and change the graphic backend to AGG, the default plot display is much nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit**

To remove gaps, set column width to one, and free x-scaling. Dropping unused factor levels (`drop = TRUE`) is an extra:

```
dfall |>
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(id, -value),y = value, fill = type), alpha = .5) +
  geom_col(width = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ case, drop = TRUE, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image: remove gaps via column width and free x-scaling]

`geom_density` or `geom_histogram` illustrate *distributions* quite well. Considering your example data:

```
dfall |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(value, color = type)) +
  facet_wrap(~ case)
```

[image: compare distributions with geom_density]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I should have precised that it is more the order and position of the red type in the distribution that I want to highligh. Like if they are found more at the beginning, the end, or equally distributed along the distribution.